# Why does mk4ht oolatex wrap up the whole folder of nearly 1 GB into .odt file?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

On Ubuntu 20.10 I am trying to use `mk4ht oolatex filename.tex` and I get (after some messages) 'System call: cd sxw-Test_2.dir; zip -r Test_2.odt * ; cd ..', which zips my whole folder of nearly 1 GB into the .odt file. This line is really some strange behavior. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: try `make4ht -f odt filename.tex` instead. It replaces `oolatex` and fixes lot of issues that `oolatex` cannot fix. It also shouldn't pack your entire directory.